# Header syntax in POST request (PYTHON)

Tags: python, api

I'm doing an API call in Python for the Spotify API and apparently I need to have the header parameter called "Authorization" take the following value:

" Base 64 encoded string that contains the client ID and client secret key. The field must have the format: Authorization: Basic  "

Does anyone know what that means, and what the exact Python syntax for that would be?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554994/spotify-api-authentication-with-python

Answer (score 0):

this is `basic` HTTP authrisation, most 
HTTP libraries will convert an authorized URLinto that automatically

```
https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@server/path
```

saving you from having to mess with headers.